# Series squeeze() not returning similar outputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
import pandas as pd

year = '2018'

idNumber = '450007'

df = pd.read_csv('FARS_data/FARS' + year + 'NationalCSV/ACCIDENT.csv')
df = df.astype(str)

print (df.loc[df['ST_CASE'] == idNumber].squeeze(axis='index'))

df = pd.read_csv('FARS_data/FARS' + year + 'NationalCSV/PERSON.csv')
df = df.astype(str)
rows = df.loc[df['ST_CASE'] == idNumber]
for i in range(len(rows.index)):
    print (rows.iloc[i].to_frame().transpose().squeeze(axis='index'))
```

The type of all the items printed is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

The reason I have a for loop for the second csv is that `rows` has two rows in it, while the first one has only one row, so I had to make the DataFrame produce two Series.

My output is below: (comments added by me)

```
#First print
STATE                  45
ST_CASE            450007
VE_TOTAL                2
VE_FORMS                2
PVH_INVL                0
PEDS                    0
PERNOTMVIT              0
PERMVIT                 2
PERSONS                 2
COUNTY                 15
CITY                 1072
DAY                     3
MONTH                   1
YEAR                 2018
DAY_WEEK                4
HOUR                    9
MINUTE                 28
NHS                     0
RUR_URB                 2
FUNC_SYS                4
RD_OWNER                1
ROUTE                   3
TWAY_ID            SR-136
TWAY_ID2              nan
MILEPT                  0
LATITUDE      32.15663889
LONGITUD         -79.1526
SP_JUR                  0
HARM_EV                12
MAN_COLL                6
RELJCT1                 0
RELJCT2                 1
TYP_INT                 1
WRK_ZONE                0
REL_ROAD                1
LGT_COND                1
WEATHER1                3
WEATHER2                0
WEATHER                 3
SCH_BUS                 0
RAIL              0000000
NOT_HOUR               99
NOT_MIN                99
ARR_HOUR               99
ARR_MIN                99
HOSP_HR                99
HOSP_MN                99
CF1                     0
CF2                     0
CF3                     0
FATALS                  1
DRUNK_DR                0
Name: 25834, dtype: object
#Second print
STATE           45
ST_CASE     450007
VE_FORMS         2
VEH_NO           1
PER_NO           1
             ...  
P_SF3            0
WORK_INJ         0
HISPANIC         7
RACE             1
LOCATION         0
Name: 64374, Length: 62, dtype: object
#Third print
STATE           45
ST_CASE     450007
VE_FORMS         2
VEH_NO           2
PER_NO           1
             ...  
P_SF3            0
WORK_INJ         8
HISPANIC         0
RACE             0
LOCATION         0
Name: 64375, Length: 62, dtype: object
```

What I want to happen is for the second two prints to look like the first one - all pretty and formatted, showing all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `pd.options.display.max_rows` is 60, while PERSON.csv was 62 rows, so it wouldn't display. Setting `pd.options.display.max_rows = 999` before running any of the code allowed everything to show.